# Multiplexer between Capacitor and Inductor (Tank circuit)

Tags: capacitor, inductor, multiplexer, resonance

I am trying to design an inductance and capacitance meter with multiple scales, to achieve this I thought a multiplexer can do the job, but it didn't.

My question is: What is wrong in this design and how can I select between the capacitors without a multiplexer?

[image]

L1 is the inductor plug.
The meter should measure the tank circuit resonance period using a comparator.

Comment: What you need is called an analog switch, not a multiplexer.

Comment: @Hearth that would still be unlikely to work due to parasitics.

Comment: @EdgarBrown It'll work a hell of a lot better than a multiplexer! But yes, it's not the best choice.

Comment: Is relay a good choice?

Comment: I don't think you have any real chance of using that 1pF capacitor, C2. The parasitics will be many times bigger.

Comment: DC supplies not shown: are you using +Vdd, -Vee, 0v Vss? And be aware that internal resistance is 100 - 200 ohms...if this adds too much damping, you won't reach LC resonance.

Comment: The switch uses large FETs, with 10 or 20 or 100 ohm channel resistances. These resistances will dampen your expected resonance, For 1uH and 1uF, the resonance is 160,000Hz, and the reactance is 1ohm.

Comment: What about the oscillator electronic, the tank circuit of inductor and selected capacitor would not oscillate continously without it? But as others noted C2 with 1 pF is useless due to parasitic capacitance. 100 pF may work but not very precisely. Electrolytic capacitors have too large tolerances of about - 50 % + 100 % for measurement of oscillation frequency to determine inductance.